# Deeplink for Metamask on mobile doesn't connect

Tags: ethereum, deep-linking, metamask, wallet

I'm having some connection issues with Metamask on mobile. It's connecting on desktop fine with this:

```js
const _provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
store.provider = _provider;
```

But, when it comes to the mobile, apparently a deep link should be used. I wrote it like the following:

```js
const dappUrl = 'xxx';
const metamaskAppDeepLink = 'https://metamask.app.link/dapp/' + dappUrl;
```

The problem is that whenever I click on the *connect wallet* on mobile, it opens first Metamask as expected, but when I click 'connect wallet' in MM, **it forwards me to the app store instead of connecting**.
I tried to do it with multiple chains (polygon and ethereum) and yet, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Metamask and re-installing from the App Store again. AFAIK that's the only way.

Remember that your wallets will be gone, so you have to enter the same seed phrase or private keys to retrieve them.